# Can't set time(0) in migration laravel 7

Tags: sql-server, laravel, migration

I can't set time(0) in sql server using migration in laravel.
This is code:

```
 $table->id('ID');
 $table->time('Start_Time', 0)->default(now()->toTimeString());
 $table->time('End_Time', 0)->default(now()->toTimeString());
 $table->string('Des', 255);
 $table->string('Note')->nullable();
 $table->datetime('Time_Created')->nullable();
 $table->bigInteger('User_Created')->nullable();
 $table->datetime('Time_Updated')->nullable();
 $table->bigInteger('User_Updated')->nullable();
 $table->boolean('IsDelete')->default(0);
```

[image]

This is the result I got.

Comment: Do you get the same result from `sp_help 'yourtablename'`? Also, maybe `default(DB::raw('getdate()'))` instead?

Comment: All I need is just set the time (0). Default getdate() is not needed, because I am using mysql. This is the result in sp_help:Column_name Type Computed Length Prec Scale Nullable TrimTrailingBlanks FixedLenNullInSource Collation
ID bigint no 8 19    0     no (n/a) (n/a) NULL
Start_Time time no 5 16    7     no (n/a) (n/a) NULL
End_Time time no 5 16    7     no (n/a) (n/a) NULL

Comment: Your question is tagged sql-server (and everything else about it is consistent with using sql server) however you are now saying you are using MySQL? Sidenote: The default value you have there is going to be precomputed so your column default will the the time the table was created rather than the time the row was insterted

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I am using 2 databases in parallel, sql server and mysql. To be able to switch back and forth between these two databases, I need to use migrations instead of writing commands directly on them.